# Como converter código .ino(arduino) em .hex?

Tags: arduino, compilação

Como converter meu código Arduino (.ino) para .hex. Eu não quero usar a IDE(arduino). Existe uma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Mas qual é a intenção de fazer isso?

Comment: Avrdude faz o upload de dados para plataforma arduino nesse formato.

Comment: Mas ele não manda o código já compilado pra lá?

Comment: De fato, ele manda as informações para EPROM copiladas, mas antes de "transformá-las" em binárias ele usa o código .hex .

Comment: Esclareca melhor, por favor: Você deseja pegar um arquivo do Arduino (*.ino) e gerar um *.hex desse arquivo sem usar a IDE do Arduino, certo? Em outas palavras, você deseja continuar utilizando as bibliotecas do Arduino, porém quer compilar tudo via linha de comando, certo?

Comment: @cantoni, exatamente isso.

Comment: ver: https://blog.arduino.cc/2018/08/24/announcing-the-arduino-command-line-interface-cli/

Answer (score 1):

Sim existe, mas não será propriamente simples devido à quantidade de livrarias e coisas que se devem ligar.

A melhor forma de ver o processo será ligar os detalhes de compilação no arduino IDE (ficheiro->preferências->mostrar mensagens detalhadas durante a compilação)

note que o arduino IDE copiará o ficheiro .ino para um ficheiro .cpp algures numa pasta temporária e trabalhará a partir daí.

No entanto o processo mostrado pelo arduino IDE pode ser simplificado um pouco, mas será sempre um osso duro.

P.S. revolvi complementar a minha resposta, pois eventualmente o utilizador não pretende gerar "manualmente" o código mas apenas uma alternativa ao arduino IDE, nesse caso existem outros IDE's que podem usar as mesmas boards e o framework arduino, tal como https://platformio.org/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode gerar o arquivo .hex e .bin na IDE do Arduino, simplesmente escreva o código, e na hora pra compilar vá em:
Sketch -> Exportar Binário Compilado.

O código vai ser compilador e na mesma pasta onde está salvo o arquivo .ino, serão gerados mais dois arquivos .hex . Um deles é com o bootloader do Arduino, e o sem esse bootloader.